# How to add a "no index" tag on every page

Tags: 9

I need help in adding a "no index" tag on several pages. Please help me with this.

Comment: The Question title does not match the Question body. The title says "every page", and the body says "several pages". Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a primary use-case of the [Metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag), and it has many other useful features.